# Error while using "mvn install"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Can anyone help me with this error ? I was using "mvn install" command in my warnings-plugin directory.
I got this error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 57:18.440s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 25 01:59:03 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/73M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project warnings: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jvnet.hudson.plugins:warnings:hpi:4.58-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-war:war:1.625.1, org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness:jar:1.625.1: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-war:war:1.625.1 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): GET request of: org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/1.625.1/jenkins-war-1.625.1.war from repo.jenkins-ci.org failed: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

My pom.xml file looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>analysis-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.65</version>
    <relativePath>../analysis-pom</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>warnings</artifactId>
  <packaging>hpi</packaging>
  <name>Warnings Plug-in</name>
  <version>4.58-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <url>http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/G4CGAQ</url>
  <description>This plug-in reads the compiler warnings from the console log file and generates a trend report.</description>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>MIT license</name>
      <comments>All source code is under the MIT license.</comments>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>LGPL</name>
      <comments>All icons are made by Carlitus (Carles Carbonell Bernado) and are under the LGPL.</comments>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>BSD license</name>
      <comments>All YUI source code is under the BSD license. Duke, the Java mascot also is under the BSD license.</comments>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>Scala License</name>
      <url>http://www.scala-lang.org/license.html</url>
      <comments>Scala icons are made by converting of http://www.scala-lang.org/resources/img/smooth-spiral.png</comments>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>Creative Commons Attribution 3.0</name>
      <url>https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0</url>
      <comments>Go mascot and logo were designed by Renée French and are covered by the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license.</comments>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>analysis-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.77</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>violations</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.11</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>analysis-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.18</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I'm on ubuntu 14.04. I installed maven using sudo apt-get install maven.

I'm writing a new parser following [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin][1] .

[1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin and just following the steps given there.

Comment: Are you behind a company firewall? In that case you might need to configure [proxy settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for Maven.

Comment: no I'm using internet at home.

Comment: you should post the content on stackoverflow. it is more stable.

Comment: content is posted now.

Comment: great. I have just answered

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to browse the repo you use to download jenkins war :

http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/

The server has difficulties to respond. Try that : 
http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/com/

So, yes, it is well a timeout problem.
Maybe temporary, maybe permanent... I don't know.
Anyway, you have three solutions :

- try again later
- configure another mvn repository in your pom.xml where the artifact exists
- download the war from another website (ex: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-war/1.625.1) 
  and put it in your maven local repository.

Comment: Actually I'm writing a new parser following https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin . I'm not familiar with maven and jenkins.

Comment: I understand. but when you declare a pom.xml you do Maven :)
To guide you, in your pom.xml, you declare dependencies and plugins. When you build this pom.xml with Maven, Maven must download all its dependencies from maven repositories (the default maven central repository and custom maven repositories). If the dependency resolution fails, the build fails. It is your case. So, you have to find a solution to bypass it. The simplest solution is downloading the artifact from internet and to put it in your m2 local repo (default :~home/.m2) at the expected place. Look at the Maven doc to know more

Comment: I ran `mvn clean install` now. and everything seems fine now. the message is                                                   
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21:12.497s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 25 03:11:52 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/385M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: is it ok ? @davidxxx

Comment: yes it is ok now :) As explained in my answer, it was a timeout problem. So, I suppose that when you have just tried, the problem was not present any longer.
Good luck for next steps :)

Comment: Is there any difference between `mvn clean install` and `mvn install` ?